# Don't catch error in angular html template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, tsconfig, angular-template

I have a method:

```
public me(a: number, b: string): void {
   b.toLowerCase();
}
```

in html template:

```
(click)="me(2)"
```

Why after compilation I haven't error in console/terminal? for example: 'Invalid number of arguments, expected 2'

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "jsxFactory": "React.createElement",
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["src/app/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: and I haven't error in browser console, for example: "cannot read property toLowerCase of undefined', but component doesn't render right

Comment: Can you please create a Stackblitz? because it is throwing error in my machine.

Comment: 2nd: your function will call on click event thats why you can't have error in terminal until you click on it.

Comment: sorry, update, for second case I use my method in property binding, like that:
`[props]="me=(2)"`

Comment: Do you have `fullTemplateTypeCheck` in tsconfig.json to `true`?

Comment: @BojanKogoj yes

Comment: If you are using AOT (Ivy), you can replace `fullTemplateTypeCheck: true` with `strictTemplates: true`. This picks up more errors.

Comment: @GunnarB. I using and after change i haven't error yet

Comment: Just to make sure, by 'after compiling' you mean that you use `ng serve` correct? If you changed the config during a serve, you will need to stop and serve again. Those changes are only picked up on the initial serve, not on save/recompile.

Comment: I know, I restarted a script :)

Comment: @GunnarB. It didn't help :/